# Select post content from one table based on id of row in another

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a WordPress multisite setup that I'm trying to run a node script against, where it loops through the database and selects all rows which contain a string in the `post_content` column of the `wp_{site-id}_post` table, and grabs the id of the site from the `wp_blogs` table based on the id of the `wp_{site-id}_post` table.

So the tables break down as follows:

wp_blogs:

```
blog_id | site_id | domain       | path  | ...

 85     |       1 | mydomain.com | /site | ...
```

wp_85_posts:

```
ID | post_author | post_date | post_date_gmt | post_content         | post_title | ...

1  |           1 | ...       | ...           | this is post content | I'm a post |
```

How can I get the domain from `wp_blogs` where `post_content` matches a LIKE clause so that it knows the `post_content` is in `wp_85_posts` and know that the domain is in `wp_blogs` based on the `blog_id`?

My current query is:

`SELECT path, blog_id, post_content FROM wp_blogs, wp_78_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%content-to-search%'`

but would like to be able to run the query without having to specify each site's post tables (wp_78_posts, for example).

Is there a clause I can use in order to avoid having to do that?

Comment: No. There isn't.

Comment: As @Strawberry says, this isn't possible in SQL. There's no way to specify database, table, or column names dynamically.

Comment: Instead of having a separate table for each site, you should have a single `wp_posts` table with a `site_id` column. Then you can join `ON wp_blogs.site_id = wp_posts.site_id`.